# Open modal containing relevant information from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ticketing system I am working on implementing and one aspect of it is to generate tables based on tickets that are either resolved or not and there is a drop down box that when it changes sends an AJAX request to another page to generate the table, this part all works. The part I am not stuck on is getting relevant information from a selected ticket into the bootstrap modal. What I mean by this is that I have a view button that is in the last column of each row on in the generated table and when they click this view I want to activate a modal that would have the ticket along with comments and a way to resolve it. I am thinking that maybe I could use the isShown function of modals to send an AJAX request to some page that could generate that information using ticket ID's I could send some how. Does this seem like a possible solution? If I would implement this solution what is the easiest way to get the ticketID sent, would I make a form for each row of the table and make a hidden field that is the id or is there an easier way? My code to create the tables is as follows:

```
if($_POST['ticketType'] == "UnresolvedTickets"){
    $selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticketsResolved = 'New' OR ticketsResolved = 'Open'";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($selectQuery);
    $stmt->execute();
    $info = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<table style='width:100%; ' class = 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo" <th>Requestor</th>";
    echo "<th>Description</th>";
    echo "<th>Type</th>";
    echo "<th>Status</th>";
    echo "<th>Severity</th>";
    echo "<th>Request Date</th>";
    echo "<th>Ticket #</th>";
    echo "<th>View Ticket</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach($info as $item){
        echo "<tr>";
        $date = $item['ticketDate'];
        $newDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', strtotime($date));
        echo "<td>{$item['ticketContact']}</td><td>{$item['ticketDescription']}</td><td>{$item['ticketType']}</td><td>{$item['ticketsResolved']}</td><td>{$item['ticketStatus']}</td><td>{$newDate}</td><td>{$item['ticketID']}</td><td><a href='http://link'>view</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}else{
    $selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticketsResolved = 'Resolved'";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($selectQuery);
    $stmt->execute();
        $info = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<table style='width:100%; ' class = 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo" <th>Requestor</th>";
    echo "<th>Description</th>";
    echo "<th>Type</th>";
    echo "<th>Status</th>";
    echo "<th>Severity</th>";
    echo "<th>Request Date</th>";
    echo "<th>Ticket #</th>";
    echo "<th>View Ticket</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach($info as $item){
        echo "<tr>";
        $date = $item['ticketDate'];
        $newDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', strtotime($date));
        echo "<td>{$item['ticketContact']}</td><td>{$item['ticketDescription']}</td><td>{$item['ticketType']}</td><td>{$item['ticketsResolved']}</td><td>{$item['ticketStatus']}</td><td>{$newDate}</td><td>{$item['ticketID']}</td><td><a href='http://link'>view</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Is there a different/easier/better way to implement this modal idea or is my idea on the right track? If my idea is on the right track I am sort of stumped on the getting the ticketID into the AJAX call to populate the modal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your PHP that creates the table rows thus:

```
echo "<td>{$item['ticketContact']}</td><td>{$item['ticketDescription']}</td><td>{$item['ticketType']}</td><td>{$item['ticketsResolved']}</td><td>{$item['ticketStatus']}</td><td>{$newDate}</td><td class="tidTD">{$item['ticketID']}</td><td class="viewTD">View</td>"
```

Note that I assigned classes to the TDs, and use those classes to:

(1) Detect clicks on the viewTD, and

(2) Locate the ticketID's input field value

Then, trap the click on the View button:

```
$(document).on('click', '.viewTD', function(){
    var tid = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tidTD input').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
         url: 'ajax.php',
        data: 'tid=' +tid,
        success: function(d){
            $('.modal-body').html(d);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    }); //END ajax
}); //END viewTD click
```

Comment: would the line: .find('.tidTD input').val(); find the ID, I 100% like this method and understand what you're doing but how does it get the idea if there is no actually input field?  does .val() grab text in between <td>'s?

Comment: Sorry, you are right -- I misread your code and thought I saw an `<input>` element between the TD tags. Just use `$(this).closest('tr').find('.tidTD').text();` instead to get the value inside the TD